# Sprite Values Must Move

Tags: python, pygame

I have a sprite and when it collides with another object I want it to increase the score that the user gets. However I am unsure how to export the fact that the sprite has collided to another part of my program. This is what I tried:

```
def checkCollision(self, sprite):
        if self.rect.colliderect(sprite.rect):
            self.x=3000
            self.score=score+100
```

However it ignore the fact the score has increased despite me having made score global.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "despite me having made score global." `score` in this case is the object's `score` attribute, and not something you can make so easily `global`.

Comment: Well if you made score global, then you have to modify the global score by doing `global score; score += 100`. To update the score in your sprite instance, do `self.score += 100`. As a side note, using globals is not recommended because it unnecessarily pollutes the global namespace. Not to mention, access to local variables is faster in CPython.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the collision function you provided is part of your player class. Making that assumption, you could simply assign the global score to = x.score (x = whatever you named that particular player object) Obviously this is less than ideal but it's a simple way to stick in the functionality you're looking for.